# I have a scenario where i want to add notification to take medicine for 3 days/ 5 days . Reminder as per user requirement

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

Here is the updated code, created a function  for this and called in viewDidLoad.I am trying to appear it for four days through loop including today.

```
 func scheduleNotification(day: Int) {

       var date = DateComponents()
       date.year = 2019
       date.month = 3
       date.day = day
       date.hour = 12
       date.minute = 30

       let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
       let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
       content.title = "Hi User"
       content.body = "Take Medicine"
       content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default


       let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification\(day)", content: content, trigger: trigger)
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
           if let error = error {
               print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
           }
       }





 override func viewDidLoad()
   {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       for index in 1...4 {
           scheduleNotification(day: index)
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Add one notification for each day.

Comment: In viewDidLoad(){for index in 1...4 {
            scheduleNotification(day: index)
        }}

Comment: sir i tried this   by adding it for per days.. but its appearing only for last day.

Comment: scheduleNotification, isn't that deprecated? You are using `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` right?

Comment: yes , I am using UNCalendarNotificationTrigger

Comment: Update the code with what you have tried using a loop and UNCalendarNotificationTrigger

Comment: You are removing all pending notifications each time you call `scheduleNotification` so only the last notification will fire. The others are removed

Answer (score 0):

In `scheduleNotification` you are calling `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`.

This will remove any previously scheduled notifications.

As you are calling `scheduleNotification` 4 times, each of the first three notifications will be cancelled by the subsequent call to `scheduleNotification`.

Only the final notification will remain.

You should remove the call to `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`.  You can call this *before* the `for` loop if you want.